# Can I use huge database MS Sql 2012 in Android application easily?

Tags: android

we are using SQL 2012 with windows software. Now we need a mobile application to access this data, it might be a huge amount of data, Can we use easily SQL Server on android applications.

Comment: IMHO you'd need some sort of service (e.g. web service, REST) to proxy between your app and the DB.

Comment: Yes. No. It depends.

Comment: This question is too broad, you can use structures so that data is fetched on demand. Something similar to lazy load.

Comment: Can I work with SQL 2012 DB easily like SQLite with my apps ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to decide where will the data stay. Is it going to be accessed via web or it'll stay in the phone locally.

If it's going to be accessed via web than you'll need to put this data on a web server and create an API to be accessed. You can use ASP .net Web API or can even use simple PHP with that (I am not sure how good php works with SQL Server databases). The mobile app will call the API to get the data.

If it's going to stay in the device then you should really use SQLite, since it's very lightweight and has good native support in Android and iOS both.